Using a venv python by default (as pip won't work with the system python)
Since I cannot use pip to install modules to the system python, I must use a venv.
What is the 'right way' to ensure that the #!/usr/bin/env python finds this venv and not the system python?

When running a command via ssh, it needs to find the python into which I can install modules via pip, so activating a venv is not an option.
Changing the shebang line is also not an option, since the script needs to work unmodified on a number of different systems so that I can manage them with git.
I am the only user of my systems, but use multiple user accounts, and don't want to have to install the modules separately for each user, so a venv per user is also not an option.


There is an argument for pip
pip install package_name --break-system-packages

See this stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-every-time-i-use-pip-3
